# Solving an Array error in codeigniter framework

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, codeigniter-2

I am trying to load my sign in page, but I get the error that:

```
Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Filename: views/sign_in.php

Line Number: 23(<?php if(in_array("ldap",$this->config->item("validation"))): ?>)
```

and in line 103 .....  where am I going wrong?

MY CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo lang('website_title')." : " . 
lang('sign_in_page_name'); 
?></title>
<?php echo $this->load->view('meta'); ?>
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="resource/css/960gs/960gs.css" 
/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resource/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<div id="content">




<div class="container_12">
<?php echo $this->load->view('logo'); ?>

        <?php if(in_array("ldap",$this->config->item("validation"))): ?>

        <div class="grid_12">
        <h2><?php echo anchor(uri_string().($this->input- 
>get('continue')?'/?continue='.urlencode($this->input- 
  >get('continue')):''), lang('sign_in_page_name')); ?></h2>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div id="ldap_validation" >

        <?php echo form_open(uri_string()."/sign_in_ldap".($this->input- 
>get('continue')?'/?continue='.urlencode($this->input- 
  >get('continue')):'')); ?>
        <?php echo form_fieldset(); ?>

            <h3><?php echo lang('windows_validation'); ?></h3>

          <div class="grid_2 alpha">
            <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_ldap_username'), 
  'sign_in_ldap_username'); ?>
         </div>
         <div class="grid_4 omega">
            <?php echo form_input(array(
                    'name' => 'sign_in_ldap_username',
                    'id' => 'sign_in_ldap_username',
                    'value' => set_value('sign_in_ldap_username'),
                    'maxlength' => '255'
                )); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('sign_in_ldap_username'); ?>
            <?php if (isset($sign_in_ldap_username_error)) : ?>
            <span class="field_error"><?php echo
            $sign_in_ldap_username_error; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="grid_2 alpha">
            <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_ldap_password'), 
 'sign_in_ldap_password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">
            <?php echo form_password(array(
                    'name' => 'sign_in_ldap_password',
                    'id' => 'sign_in_ldap_password',
                    'value' => set_value('sign_in_ldap_password')
                )); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('sign_in_ldap_password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php if (isset($recaptcha)) : ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <?php echo $recaptcha; ?>
        </div>
        <?php if (isset($sign_in_recaptcha_error)) : ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <span class="field_error"><?php echo 
$sign_in_recaptcha_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <span>
                <?php echo form_button(array(
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'class' => 'button',
                        'content' => lang('sign_in_ldap_sign_in')
                    )); ?>
            </span>
            <span>
                <?php echo form_checkbox(array(
                        'name' => 'sign_in_ldap_remember',
                        'id' => 'sign_in_ldap_remember',
                        'value' => 'checked',
                        'checked' => $this- 
 >input>post('sign_in_ldap_remember'),
                        'class' => 'checkbox'
                    )); ?>
                <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_ldap_remember_me'), 
   'sign_in_ldap_remember'); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <p><?php echo lang('sign_in_ldap_forgot_your_password'); ?> 
     <br />
            <?php echo sprintf(lang('sign_in_ldap_dont_have_account'), 
   lang('sign_in_ldap_sign_up_now')); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

     </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (in_array("simple",$this->config->item("validation"))): ?>

    <div class="grid_12">
                        <?php if (in_array("ldap",$this->config- 
    >item("validation"))): ?>
                            <h2>Or</h2>
                        <?php else: ?>
        <h2><?php echo anchor(uri_string().($this->input- 
   >get('continue')?'/?continue='.urlencode($this->input- 
    >get('continue')):''), lang('sign_in_page_name')); ?></h2>
                        <?php endif; ?>
       </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
       <div class="grid_6">
        <?php echo form_open(uri_string().($this->input- 
  >get('continue')?'/?continue='.urlencode($this->input- 
   >get('continue')):'')); ?>
        <?php echo form_fieldset(); ?>
        <h3><?php echo lang('sign_in_heading'); ?></h3>
        <?php if (isset($sign_in_error)) : ?>
        <div class="grid_6 alpha omega">
            <div class="form_error"><?php echo $sign_in_error; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="grid_2 alpha">
            <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_username_email'), 
    'sign_in_username_email'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">
            <?php echo form_input(array(
                    'name' => 'sign_in_username_email',
                    'id' => 'sign_in_username_email',
                    'value' => set_value('sign_in_username_email'),
                    'maxlength' => '24'
                )); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('sign_in_username_email'); ?>
            <?php if (isset($sign_in_username_email_error)) : ?>
            <span class="field_error"><?php echo 
   $sign_in_username_email_error; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="grid_2 alpha">
            <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_password'), 
   'sign_in_password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">
            <?php echo form_password(array(
                    'name' => 'sign_in_password',
                    'id' => 'sign_in_password',
                    'value' => set_value('sign_in_password')
                )); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('sign_in_password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php if (isset($recaptcha)) : ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <?php echo $recaptcha; ?>
        </div>
        <?php if (isset($sign_in_recaptcha_error)) : ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <span class="field_error"><?php echo 
   $sign_in_recaptcha_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <span>
                <?php echo form_button(array(
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'class' => 'button',
                        'content' => lang('sign_in_sign_in')
                    )); ?>
            </span>
            <span>
                <?php echo form_checkbox(array(
                        'name' => 'sign_in_remember',
                        'id' => 'sign_in_remember',
                        'value' => 'checked',
                        'checked' => $this->input- 
   >post('sign_in_remember'),
                        'class' => 'checkbox'
                    )); ?>
                <?php echo form_label(lang('sign_in_remember_me'), 
   'sign_in_remember'); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="prefix_2 grid_4 alpha omega">
            <p><?php echo anchor('account/forgot_password', 
   lang('sign_in_forgot_your_password')); ?><br />
            <?php echo sprintf(lang('sign_in_dont_have_account'), 
   anchor('account/sign_up', lang('sign_in_sign_up_now'))); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6">
        <h3><?php echo sprintf(lang('sign_in_third_party_heading')); ?> 
    </h3>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($this->config- 
    >item('third_party_auth_providers') as $provider) : ?>
            <li class="third_party <?php echo $provider; ?>"><?php echo 
   anchor('account/connect_'.$provider, lang('connect_'.$provider), 
                array('title'=>sprintf(lang('sign_in_with'), 
    lang('connect_'.$provider)))); ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
           <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The error message is:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Filename: views/sign_in.php

Line Number: 23
```

Answer (score 0):

High chances that `$this->config->item("validation")` is a `boolean`, but you are trying to find strings `'simple'` and `'ldap'` inside it like in `array`.

This is, probably, your problem, but I can't really help solving it, because I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve with this code.

```
<?php if (in_array("simple",$this->config->item("validation"))): ?>

<?php if(in_array("ldap",$this->config->item("validation"))): ?>
```

Comment: this is the view for the sign in page

Comment: You need to tell more to get the proper right answer. Did you var_dump($this->config->item("validation"))? If yes, what is inside? Where is it coming from? Why do you expecting an array there?